# Is there a way to prevent a period from automatically being entered into an EditText?

Tags: android, android-layout

For `inputType="text"`, if the user enters some text, then enters at least two consecutive spaces after the last non-space character, a period is automatically placed immediately after the last non-space character.  It's clearly assuming the end of a sentence has occurred.

Example:  `"The mysteries of Android.  Are myriad."`

However, I want my user to be able to enter any number of space-delimited substrings into the EditText without any other characters being inserted automatically.

Example:  `"The    Greatest   Show on     Earth"`

How can this be achieved?  The documentation for class InputType does not address this issue. I'd like to avoid using a TextWatcher, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Just figured out that, if one long-presses the SpaceBar when entering a space, the period does not get automatically inserted.

It would still be good to know how the automatic insertion of the period, and any other characters, can be programmatically prevented.

Comment: any update on how to prevent it from happening?

Comment: using ```android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"``` prevents a period from being added after double tapping space. Not sure if there is another xml attribute to prevent it from happening

Comment: @DIRTY DAVE: I've not found a way to programmatically control this behavior.  However, I did discover a device setting, "Double-space period", that, when disabled, prevents the period from being inserted upon typing consecutive spaces.  On a Google Pixel 4a, it's accessible via Settings | System | Languages & Input | On-screen Keyboard | Gboard | Text correction, under the "Corrections" section.  It's also available via the Settings icon when the soft keyboard is displayed.